# Updating a trial webform with a new trialforce template

Tags: managed-package, isv, partner, trial, trialforce

Our TSO was approved with a previous version of our template. Now we have updated our template and want our webform to be associated with the new template instead of the first template. I have already created new templates and created a new trial but the trial created is off of old template. I quickly skimmed through the webform html and did not see anywhere where the template id was specified. How can I make sure the new trials are created using the new template?

Comment: Same instructions as creating a new one: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/trialforce_creating_template.htm

Comment: Please post your current html so we can point where the templateId is - it should be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to log a case. The following paragraph was part of instructions from SF when I first received the web form:

> "4. If you want to make changes to your trial experience, please make
>   the edits in your source org, create a new template, and log another
>   case so support can update your formname with the latest template.
>   Please provide your formname, template ID, and source org ID in the
>   case description."

Another option is to create a new trial from Environment Hub. It allows you to specify what template you want to use to spin off trials